# Насколько корректно SimpleDateFormat отражает время в часах, минутах, секундах

Tags: время, simpledateformat

У меня есть время в миллисекундах выполнения некоего задания, я хочу отразить его в формате 
часы:минуты:секунды

Ниже привожу 2 способа, а это результат выполнения:
дано longTime = 18624, в результате получаем strTime1 = "03:00:18", strTime = "00:18"

Подскажите откуда берутся 3 часа в первом способе?

```
public static String getStrTime(long longTime){
    // 1 способ
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String strTime1 = df.format(longTime);

    // 2 способ
        long time = longTime/1000;
        String strTime;
        int ch = (int) time/(60*60);
        int min = (int) (time-ch*60*60)/60;
        int s = (int) time-ch*60*60 - min*60;

        if (ch>0) {
            strTime = "" + ((ch>9)?"":"0") + ch + ":" + ((min>9)?"":"0") + min + ":" + ((s>9)?"":"0") + s;
        } else {
            strTime = "" + ((min>9)?"":"0") + min + ":" + ((s>9)?"":"0") + s;
        }
        return strTime;
    }
```

Comment: И как с этим часовым поясом бороться? Или в моем случае, лучше не бороться, а оставить второй вариант?

Comment: Можете указать явно таймзону для `SimpleDateFormat` через `setTimeZone`, а можете оставить второй способ, тут что вам больше нравится скорее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что во втором случае вы просто считаете сколько секунд/минут/часов в данном количестве миллисекунд, а во первом способое переводите [Unix epoch time](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) в дату-время и при этом по умолчанию используется часовой пояс вашего компьютера (который на три часа отличается от GMT).

Если вы добавите в формат вывода еще и дату (например `"dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"`), то увидите, что в первом случае дата - 1 января 1970 года.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, хоть что-то прояснилось